# MySQL Rounding Numbers

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

HI,

I have just updated a price table with VAT increases but this has left me with ugly numbers ie `22.78, 33.24` etc..

Is there a script I can call to zero the decimals so that `22.78 = 23.00` and `33.24 = 33.00` etc...

Thank in advance..

Comment: here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using [ROUND()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)

```
update table set myfield = ROUND(myfield)
```